# How do I make before_filter run when using send method in Rails3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My `foo` controller is defined as such:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => :some_action
  def show
    send(some_action)
  end

  def some_action
  end

  private
  def authenticate
    # redirect user if not authenticated
  end
end
```

Given I am not logged in, when I navigate directly to the `some_action` action, I am redirected to the front page. When I navigate to the show action, however, I am not.
The before_filter doesn't run when I call the action through the `send`.

Right now, my workaround is to call `authenticate` directly from my `some_action` action.

Any ideas about why the before_filter doesn't get called through `send` and how to fix it? Is this intended behavior **for `send` being called through a controller**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`send` is a ruby metaprogramming method. You should only be using it in special circumstances, rather than all the time.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:show, :some_action]

  def show
    ...
  end

  def some_action
    ...
  end
end
```